# ADC reading on ATtiny13, without dedicated clock?

Tags: adc, avr, clock, attiny

I am in a design phase of a small circuit which is intended to measure an external voltage, with an ATtiny13.

This AVR has a dedicated ADC hardware, which is suitable for my needs (need to detect whether voltage is above X or not in long term, no spikes)

Now I am in front of a question if I need dedicated clock (xtal, osc) to make these ADC measurements reliable.

I have strict size constraints and the PCB must remain as small as possible.

Also, PCB will be carried to different regions with different temperatures (every region fits well into AVR's working temperature ranges).

So, can I skip using a dedicated clock if I need to measure (not-quickly-changing) voltage?

Comment: What does the datasheet say about clocking options? Have you read it?

Comment: Why you did not use an internal clock?

Comment: I wish to use internal clock, yes. Otherwise core would be stopped :)

Comment: Clocking options can be vary from 50-200kHz. What I wish to know if 3V would be X on 20degrees, would it also be X on 40degrees if I use the internal clock (which I think varies by temperature).

Comment: Surely it reads in the datasheet. And if you just need to read if voltage is below or above a threshold why would the clock speed matter? Unless you need to communicate the result somewhere in some way with some speed and tolerance, which you don't say.

Comment: Do you require an accurate time reference for your voltage readings? It sounds not. Any clock source that keeps the MCU going, and is within specification for the ADC, ought to suffice to simply read a voltage level.

Comment: I don't have any time constraints on readings, just want to make sure I don't need to calibrate my values each and every time when the unit changes regions to keep *X* constant for *3V*.

Comment: The internal reference voltage is not very precise (+/- 10%), varies from chip to chip and has a temperature drift. Unfortunately there is no option to use an external reference, except you provide a precise VCC. So you will have a lot of trouble calibrating the boards. There are other MCUs in this family, where you can connect an external reference. Another trick is, to connect a good reference chip to a spare ADC channel, measure both and do some math to get a hopefully acceptable precision.

Comment: If the input to MCU is voltage and it samples it with ADC, what is the output from MCU, how it controls the rest of the stuff with the info about voltage? GPIO, UART, SPI, USB, or what?

Comment: @Justme: pure GPIO: if voltage is above 3V, green LED, otherwise red LED.

Comment: @Jens: VCC is rock solid 5.0V :)

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure where your impression comes from about needing a crystal for the ADC.  From the [datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/doc2535.pdf):

> The ATtiny13 features a 10-bit successive approximation ADC. A block diagram of the ADC is
> shown in Figure 14-1.

Successive approximation ADCs are fairly insensitive to clock rates, so your worries are unfounded.

[image]

Further down in the same datasheet it says:

> The ADC module contains a prescaler, which generates an acceptable ADC clock frequency
> from any CPU frequency above 100 kHz. The prescaling is set by the ADPS bits in ADCSRA.

So, just make sure the thing gets an acceptable clock, and you're done.

Comment: That phrase in the datasheet in your last quote is a bit misleading IMO, in that it seems to imply the prescaler would automatically generate an acceptable clock frequency. But as the follow-up implies, that's not true, they'll have to set it up properly and know the nominal frequency they're running the AVR at. No biggie, just  that I find the phrase there odd (and I may myself have been momentarily misled by it, sometime in the past).

Comment: Well, always, read the datasheet.

Answer (score 1):

Since the only thing the MCU does is use ADC and simply lights up a LED based on result, no external clocks are needed. The factory calibration is done at 3.0V and 25°C and it only has +/- 10% tolerance, which makes it unusable for e.g. UART serial comms.

Just use the default MCU clock source settings for the internal oscillator, and use it. Make sure you know what the default frequency is, as your code needs to configure the ADC clock prescaler value so that the ADC clock is within the specified range to get the specified accuracy.